# How to use T-SQL to call exec(@sql) to change current database?

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In SQL server is there any way to get the 'use database' command to accept a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969046/in-sql-server-is-there-any-way-to-get-the-use-database-command-to-accept-a-var)

We can change the database by their name is no problem as below

```
USE master
GO
```

But I need this in a script and have the database name in a variable. How to make this?

```
select @cmd = N'use ' + @oldDb  + N';'
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

That doesn't work - the current database stays the same after the execution.

Is something possible at all?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the problem is with using GO within a dynamic sql statement, because execute sql doesn't support multiple batches. Please see this link for the solution. [Change Database with Dynamic SQL](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/3974/database-use-issues-with-dynamic-sql)

Comment: I want to change the database context using T-SQL without the `GO` command - I have updated the script to obmit the `go`

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps there's a valid reason for this, but if possible I would recommend naming the DB by name in your script where required.  for example

databasename.table.owner.field

Comment: It's a nice work-around. Though, my automation query script will have to replace the database name when it is changed - this shouldn't be acceptable when my script is handed to other developers in the team; they just need to enter the database name once and from then, just hit run to see the result. Thanks any way